# Corollary of 1.11 in Atiyah and Macdonald

Tags: commutative-algebra

I would like to prove the following variation of 1.11 in AM.

If $\mathfrak{p_1},\ldots,\mathfrak{p_n}$ are prime ideals and $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal such that $\mathfrak{a}\neq\mathfrak{p_i}$ for each $i$. Then $\mathfrak{a}\neq\bigcup \mathfrak{p}_i$.

Any ideas how to go about this? Or possibly provide a counter example.

Comment: A union of ideals is very rarely an ideal.  Including a union of prime ideals.

Comment: This is a version of what is known as prime avoidance. It holds under more general conditions: if  the ring contains an infinite field, or if at most two of the ideals are not prime. There is a proof on page 91 of Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra.*

Comment: That's the contrapositive of the *prime avoidance lemma*.